# Copy website feature in visual studio 2010 is not working because my local pc code is under source control

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

This is my first time posting a question in StackOverflow. Pls forgive me if I made any mistake.

The condition is such: I have codes inside my laptop that is under source control by a TFS (Team Foundation Server) server in the company and I have a web server which I upload the codes so that user can browse the pages. So there are 3 main items here: the TFS server, my laptop and the web server.
When I try to check in/out between my laptop and TFS server using Visual Studio, no problem.

When I try to use "Copy Web Site" feature in Visual Studio to upload my laptop's code to the web server, no problem too.

However, when I try to use "Copy Web Site" feature in Visual Studio to DOWNLOAD the web server's code into my laptop, then it will says the job is completed, but in actual fact, it has not done anything because the fact is laptop's code is under source control and it cannot overwrite it.

The only solution is I have to "check out" the local laptop's code before I can successfully DOWNLOAD from web server into my laptop. This is very troublesome and annoying if I have many files to DOWNLOAD. Is there another solution to this problem?

Another question is, is there any better way to configure the relationship of these 3 items?
Sorry for such a long question.
I cannot post any images because I don't have the "10 reputation" rights required by stackoverflow.
Thanks

Comment: Note: VS & TFS 2010 drops out of support this month (July 2015)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest answer is to use a local workspace, but unfortunately local workspaces aren't an option unless you're using both Visual Studio 2012 and TFS 2012.

The basic problem here is that when you use a server workspace, files are read-only on your file system until you explicitly check them out of source control. Local workspaces don't have that necessity.

The bigger question here is why you want to grab files **from** the web server. You're using source control. If people are making changes to the code directly in the web server without going through source control, that is a huge problem that should be addressed immediately.

Comment: Daniel, thanks a lot for your help. I have upload the image files to Dropbox and here is the link, hope this will help explain the relationship of the 3 items.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7g9onvpdeis6pgj/AAABRR3VZXllpKXPRM7AZlJha?dl=0

Comment: Daniel, the reason why we need to grab files from web server is many times, other programmers upload to web server during testing and forget to checkin the code to TFS.

Comment: Then the root cause of your problem is that people aren't using source control. That's a people problem; on a team I was running, this would be something that led to stern warnings, write-ups, and eventual firing. There's no excuse for "forgetting" to use source control other than gross incompetence.

Comment: Daniel, Thank you so much for your kind and affirmative advise. Appreciate that.    ;-)